# Check if Cursor is in groupBox1 or groupBox2 C#

Tags: c#, groupbox, acceptbutton

i have 2 groupBoxes, both with one TextBox and one Button.

When i am in groupBox1 and write something in textBox1 and i Press the Enter Button, the Button in groupBox1 should be pushed, same Thing when i am in groupBox2 and write something there in textBox2.

Something like

```
if (Focus is on groupbox1 == true)
    this.AcceptButton = button1;
else if(Focus is on groupbox2 == true)
    this.AcceptButton = button2;
```

Comment: When you type your focus will be in text box 1 so change your code accordingly it will work

Comment: Use the Enter event of the textboxes.

Comment: You can use the `.Focused` property from the groupbox. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focused(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In WPF, you also have `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Passant, ty this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the enter event for toggling the focus

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AcceptButton = button1;
}
private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AcceptButton = button2;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("First button clicked");
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Second button clicked ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe on `TextBox` `KeyDown` event:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(tb_KeyDown);

static void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //enter key is down
    }
}
```